# What kind of cable and connectors are these?

Tags: wiring, plumbing

My old circulation pumps were connected by armored cable. However, on pre built systems I've see a different kind of cable. It looks almost like an appliance cable with plastic terminators between the pumps and box. Is this something that is generally available? Any issues with issues with code, as long as it's in the open?

Note: I understand the attached picture shows electronic valves and not pumps, but the wiring and connectors are the type in question.

[image: Rubberized Cable Connection]

Answer (score 3):

Those are not connectors but are "Cable Gland" style strain reliefs similar to this one:

[image: LAPP Cable Gland]

While this is not the only manufacturer of these products, it is one example:

[LAPP USA](https://lappusa.lappgroup.com/)